# Create Page Persistence with Tabulator

Tags: javascript, php, tabulator

I'm trying to enable a user to be able to leave the page with Tabulator on it and come back and it loads the same view they had before (including the page they were on, filters, and sorters they had enabled).

I have tried making it work using Tabulator's persist feature (as suggested below) but I get an error of: *Pagination Error - Requested page is out of range of 1 - 1: 3*

```
        //define new tabulator instance
        var table = new Tabulator("#production-data-table", {
            ajaxURL:"scripts/order_status.php?action=fetch_production_data", //ajax URL
            pagination:"remote",
            persistenceMode: "local",
            persistenceID: "production-data",
            persistence: {
                 sort: true, //persist column sorting
                 filter: true, //persist filter sorting
                 group: true, //persist row grouping
                 page: true, //persist page
                 columns: true, //persist columns
            },
            ajaxFiltering:true,
            ajaxSorting:true,
            layout:"fitColumns",
            columns:[
                {title:"Enterprise", field:"Enterprise", sorter:"string", width:100, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Job Number", field:"Job Number", sorter:"number", width:100, headerSort:false},
                {title:"LN #", field:"LN #", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:80, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Description", field:"Description", sorter:"string", headerSort:false},
                {title:"QTY", field:"QTY", sorter:"string", headerSort:false, align: 'center', width: 40,},
                {title:"AS400 Ship Date", field:"AS400 Ship Date", sorter:"date", align:"center", width:100},
                {title:"Exp. Ship", field:"Est Ship", sorter:"date", align:"center", width:100, headerSort:false},
                //{title:"QC", field:"QC", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Pole Barn", field:"Pole Barn", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Thermoforming", field:"Thermoforming", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Vinyl/Paint", field:"Vinyl/Paint", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"FA1", field:"Fnl Asmb 1", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"FA2", field:"Fnl Asmb 2", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Crating", field:"Crating", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Shipping", field:"Shipping", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"New", field:"New", visible:false},
                {title:"Revised", field:"Revised", visible:false},
            ],
            ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); //parse response
                var array_to_output = obj['tabulator_get_session'];

                console.debug(obj['tabulator_get_session']);
                console.debug(obj['current_page']);

                return response;
            },

            rowFormatter:function(row) {

                var data = row.getData();
                var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.getData()));
                var orderNew = data['New'];
                var orderRevised = data['Revised'];

                if ( orderNew == 1 ) {
                    row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#69db88";
                    row.getElement().style.fontWeight = "bold";
                }

                if ( orderRevised == 1 ) {
                    row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#dbd069";
                    row.getElement().style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    row.getElement().style.fontStyle = "italic";
                }

            },
            placeholder:"No Data Available", //display message to user on empty table

        });
```

I would have left a comment instead of editing the post. But the website won't allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following  codeblock for Version 4.6:

```
        //define new tabulator instance
        var table = new Tabulator("#production-data-table", {
            ajaxURL:"scripts/order_status.php?action=fetch_production_data", //ajax URL
            pagination:"remote",
            persistenceMode: "local",
            persistenceID: "production-data",
            persistence: {
                 sort: true, //persist column sorting
                 filter: true, //persist filter sorting
                 group: true, //persist row grouping
                 page: true, //persist page
                 columns: true, //persist columns
            },
            ajaxFiltering:true,
            ajaxSorting:true,
            layout:"fitColumns",
            columns:[
                {title:"Enterprise", field:"Enterprise", sorter:"string", width:100, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Job Number", field:"Job Number", sorter:"number", width:100, headerSort:false},
                {title:"LN #", field:"LN #", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:80, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Description", field:"Description", sorter:"string", headerSort:false},
                {title:"QTY", field:"QTY", sorter:"string", headerSort:false, align: 'center', width: 40,},
                {title:"AS400 Ship Date", field:"AS400 Ship Date", sorter:"date", align:"center", width:100},
                {title:"Exp. Ship", field:"Est Ship", sorter:"date", align:"center", width:100, headerSort:false},
                //{title:"QC", field:"QC", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Pole Barn", field:"Pole Barn", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Thermoforming", field:"Thermoforming", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Vinyl/Paint", field:"Vinyl/Paint", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"FA1", field:"Fnl Asmb 1", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"FA2", field:"Fnl Asmb 2", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Crating", field:"Crating", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Shipping", field:"Shipping", sorter:"string", formatter:"html", align:'center', width:101, resizable:false, headerSort:false},
                {title:"New", field:"New", visible:false},
                {title:"Revised", field:"Revised", visible:false},
            ],
            ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); //parse response
                var array_to_output = obj['tabulator_get_session'];

                console.debug(obj['tabulator_get_session']);
                console.debug(obj['current_page']);

                return response;
            },

            rowFormatter:function(row) {

                var data = row.getData();
                var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.getData()));
                var orderNew = data['New'];
                var orderRevised = data['Revised'];

                if ( orderNew == 1 ) {
                    row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#69db88";
                    row.getElement().style.fontWeight = "bold";
                }

                if ( orderRevised == 1 ) {
                    row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#dbd069";
                    row.getElement().style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    row.getElement().style.fontStyle = "italic";
                }

            },
            placeholder:"No Data Available", //display message to user on empty table
            //ajaxLoaderError:"<div>New Error new error new error</div>",
            dataLoaded: function(data) {
                table.setPage(<?=$_SESSION['tabulator_get']['pagination']['current_page']?>);
            },

        });
```

This should allow you to store the table state in localStorage for easy use.

Documentation Link: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/persist

**EDIT:**

After doing some looking at the code block, it seems as if you are missing some required arguments for remote pagination. See docs here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/page#remote

Comment: Just within my website. Basically from an order listing page to an order details page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26259902)

Comment: @ysf Added answer for the asker to my post. Sorry for that.